# Hibernate 4.3 error with mapping file

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, mapping

I get an error; however, I can not figure out why I'm getting this error. The first `class` element doesn't give any error however the second `class` element gives the error. (NB: I have other mappings but it is a repeat of the same error so I didn't worry to put the entire file)

> "The content of element type "class" must match
>
> "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)"

Any help would be appreciated:

Code

```
<class name = "cdd.model.User" table = "app_user">
    <id name = "userID" column = "user_id" type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"/>
    </id>
   
    <property name = "email" column = "email" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>  
    <property name = "fullName" column = "full_name" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "passwordHash" column = "password_hash" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "centre" column = "centre" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "accessLevel" column = "access_level" type = "org.hibernate.type.IntegerType"/>

    <set name="acceptedQuestions" table="accepted_questions_by_user">
        <key column="user_id"/>
        <many-to-many column="question_id"
                      unique="true"
                      class="cdd.model.Question"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name = "cdd.model.Category" table ="category" > 
    <!--> Primary Key <!-->  
    <id name ="categoryID" column = "category_id" type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType">
        <generator class = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator" />
    </id>

    <property name = "title" column = "title" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "description" column = "description" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType" />
    
    <join table = "category" >
        <key column = "category_id"/>
        <many-to-one name="category" column = "category_id" not-null = "true"/>
    </join>
    
    <set name = "questions" table = "category_questions" cascade = "all"  inverse = "true">
        <key column = "category_id" not-null = "true" />
        <one-to-many class = "cdd.model.Question"/> 
    </set>
    
</class>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the join tag part after set

```
<class name = "cdd.model.User" table = "app_user">
    <id name = "userID" column = "user_id" type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"/>
    </id>

    <property name = "email" column = "email" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>  
    <property name = "fullName" column = "full_name" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "passwordHash" column = "password_hash" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "centre" column = "centre" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "accessLevel" column = "access_level" type = "org.hibernate.type.IntegerType"/>

 <set name="acceptedQuestions" table="accepted_questions_by_user">
        <key column="user_id"/>
        <many-to-many column="question_id"
                      unique="true"
                      class="cdd.model.Question"/>
 </set>
</class>
<class name = "cdd.model.Category" table ="category" > 

    <id name ="categoryID" column = "category_id" type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType">
        <generator class = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator" />
    </id>

    <property name = "title" column = "title" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType"/>
    <property name = "description" column = "description" type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType" />

    <set name = "questions" table = "category_questions" cascade = "all"  inverse = "true">
        <key column = "category_id" not-null = "true" />
        <one-to-many class = "cdd.model.Question"/> 
    </set>

    <join table = "category" >
        <key column = "category_id"/>
        <many-to-one name="category" column = "category_id" not-null = "true"/>
    </join>

</class>
```

Comment: Hey can you check out my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097647/java-hibernate-mapping-file-not-working) maybe you can help me out